# Horizontal ScrollView adapt to content size (React Native)

Tags: react-native, expo, scrollview

I'm having some troubles with the ScrollView Component of React Native. I want my horizontal ScrollView to fit to the height of its children. I found this Solution in a tutorial:

```
 <View>
      <ScrollView
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
        ref={scrollView}
        horizontal
        onContentSizeChange={() => scrollView?.current?.scrollToEnd()}>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          {imageUris.map((uri) => (
            <View key={uri} style={styles.image}>
              <ImageInput
                imageUri={uri}
                onChangeImage={() => onRemoveImage(uri)}
              />
            </View>
          ))}
          <ImageInput onChangeImage={(uri) => onAddImage(uri)} />
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
```

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
  image: {
    paddingRight: 10,
  },
})
```

In the tutorial it is working fine but on my machine the ScrollView is not visible at all.

What could the reason for this behavior?

Comment: please use the flexGrow:0 in your scrollView style and let me know the result

Comment: @MehdiNasiriPoor Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately it's still not visible when setting style or contentContainerStyle to flexGrow:0